# Connecting to an Agilent E44980A with a Raspberry Pi 3 with PyVISA

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, pyvisa

I have an Agilent E4980A Precision LCR meter and wanted to talk to it with my raspberry Pi 3B+ using pyvisa and a LAN cable. However, I'm not sure whether it is connecting properly.

I've already installed the pyvisa library and then ran some code which is in the documentation. However, I'm not sure that the result is as expected and what it should say if the LAN connection is working.

So far I have written this code and get the following result:

```py
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import visa
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
>>> print(rm.list_resources())
(u'ASRL/dev/ttyAMA0::INSTR',)
>>>
```

I am not sure what the u'ASRL/dev/ttyAMAO::INSTR', means so maybe someone could explain that to me. What should the result be if the LAN connection is working also?

Answer (score 0):

This is your list of available resources on your device. It looks like their is a serial connection based on the tty symbol.