# How can I communicate to a device via TCP/IP in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have an Agilent (Keysight) E4980A LCR meter. If I install the Keysight IO Libraries suite I can connect to the device. This means, at least I have the right LAN (cross-over!) cable.
If I send the command send the command `*IDN?`, I get the response:
`Agilent Technologies,E4980A,MY46203491,A.06.17`

So, that's working fine.

However, I want to address the device from own Python applications (Python 3.7, Windows 10).
I started from [this instruction](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) and had to find out that you need some "minor" adaptions (i.e. `bytes(str,encoding)` instead of just a string and `print()`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

TCP_IP = '169.254.215.142'
TCP_PORT = 5024
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = bytes("*IDN?",'ansi')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print("received data:", data)
```

What is the Port? The E4980A manual says:

> A socket is an endpoint for network connection; port 5024 and port
> 5025 are provided for the sockets for the E4980A/AL. Port 5024 is
> provided for conversational control using telnet (user interface
> program for the TELNET protocol) and port 5025 for control from a
> program.

If I use Port 5025 I get a timeout.
If I use Port 5024 and send the command `*IDN?` or no matter what I send, I get the response:

```
received data: b'Welcome to E4980A SCPI parser.\r\n\r\nSCPI> '
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is `socket` the wrong tool? Am I using the wrong protocol?

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57165271/7295599), however, using `pyvisa` and no solution.

Comment: I know nothing about your instrument, but read in the manual that they set a 5 second timeout. Maybe you can try that - `socket.settimeout(None)` or `socket.settimeout(5.0)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your suggestion and for checking the manual. If I set a timeout, I sometimes get back `b'Welcome to E4980A SCPI parser.\r\n\r\nSCPI> \xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03'`  and sometimes the above message without `\x..` characters.

Comment: Clutching at straws... maybe try `time.sleep(1)` between `send()` and `recv()`

Comment: This is evidently a telnet-style protocol being used here on port 5024, so your client must mimic that, but it's not. I've never actually programmed such a thing (I just use the telnet command-line) but there's a built-in library for [client-side telnet](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) that might be worth looking at. But it sounds like port 5025 is specifically designed for programmers and you'll need more information about how the protocol works on that port. I'm not talking about TCP but rather the protocol that runs on top of that.

Comment: Use port 5025 and send a `'\n'` (newline) after the command.  TCP is a streaming protocol and newline is often part of the protocol to terminate a text-based command; otherwise the server is likely waiting for more bytes and that's why it times out.  Port 5024 is telnet and is sending a "hello" message before any commands are even sent.  You have to follow the telnet protocol for communication, which also expects proper line endings.

Comment: [SCPI standard](https://www.ivifoundation.org/docs/scpi-99.pdf) (Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments).

Comment: Specifically, try `s.sendall(b'*IDN?\n')`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks a lot! Ouch, so easy. Why can't these communication examples (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) be complete and working right away? There is a lot of uncomplete, non-working or outdated crap out there. Actually, btw `pyusb` is taking care about the lineend character. If you formulate your comment as a short answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: The example is correct. TCP just sends and receives bytes in the same order but not with the same breaks between sends, just like separate writes to a file can’t be determined.  A protocol must be followed to know where the message breaks are. In this case it is new lines but it could be fixed-sized messages following a structure or a fixed-sized “length” followed by data message.  It would be nice if every TCP example stressed that

Comment: Try using a tool like `nc` (netcat) to connect. Chances are that you'll get a prompt a it will accept `help` or `?` comand. If you will be able to manually get the desired data, the software has to mimic your steps. Small note regarding the usage of telnet clients: the original telnet protocol starts with an option negotiation. Some telnet-like UI-s (basically a command line with a prompt) don't do that.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72819042/timeline) attracted both a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser and a regular plagiariser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, the following finally works for me. As [Mark Tolonen pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819042/how-can-i-communicate-to-a-device-via-tcp-ip-in-python/77618802#comment128627324_72819042), it is necessary to add a lineend character, here `"\n"`. Furthermore, in contrast to the [example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) which I started with, you have to send bytes, where Python's `bytes()` requires some encoding where it seems to work with `ansi`, `ASCII` or `utf8`.

**Script:**

```
### communicate via LAN to Agilent E4980A
import socket

TCP_IP      = '169.254.215.142'  # or whatever address you'll find on the E4980A screen
TCP_PORT    = 5025
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def query(cmd):
    s.send(bytes(cmd+"\n",'ansi'))
    return s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf8')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(3.0)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

print(query("*IDN?"))

s.close()
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Agilent Technologies,E4980A,MY46203491,A.06.17
```

Device screen in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's neat you got it working with sockets, but if you've already installed the VISA driver, using `pyvisa` is the way to go. I'm not using the Agilent (Keysight) E4980A, but it should be similar.

On the computer you installed the Keysight IO Libraries, use the Keysight Connection Expert application to add your LAN device, then the following code should work:

```
% py
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvisa
>>> rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
>>> rm.list_resources()
('TCPIP0::192.168.1.15::inst0::INSTR')
>>> inst=rm.open_resource('TCPIP0::192.168.1.15::inst0::INSTR')
>>> inst.query('*IDN?')
'Agilent Technologies,N9040B\n'
```

In the Keysight Connection Expert you can also assign aliases so you can do things like:

```
>>> inst=rm.open_resource('MyDevice')
```

Comment: Sorry, for not having given any response. I almost gave up, but now retrying. When I run your code, I get the response `('USB0::0x0957::0x0909::my46203491::0::INSTR',)`. But when I continue with  `inst = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x0957::0x0909::MY46203491::0::INSTR')` I will get an error: `pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.` So, driver missing or wrong driver? How to check whether I have a compatible driver installed?

Comment: Ok, sorry again... I messed up the drivers with Zadig, because for getting PySUB to run, I was reading that you need to install another USB driver `libusbK.sys`. However, with this, Keysight IO Suite will not work anymore. Now, I managed to re-install the original driver and now it seems to work with IO-Suite **and** `pyvisa` :-). I am just wondering how I could get it to run without installing MBs or GBs of IO-Suite?

Comment: +1 you didn't answer my question about TCP, but you solved the general problem of communication to that device (+100 bounty). I stupidly tried your script just with the wrong driver.

Answer (score -4):

You're on the right track. You're using the correct IP and port. The problem you're encountering is that the LCR meter doesn't immediately return a response after receiving a command. It returns the prompt 'SCPI> ' to indicate that it's ready to receive more commands.

After sending a command, you need to wait for the LCR meter to return a response before calling s.recv(). One way to do this is by using a loop to read the data from the socket until the expected response is received. Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import time

TCP_IP = '169.254.215.142'
TCP_PORT = 5024
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = bytes("*IDN?",'ansi')
EXPECTED_RESPONSE = bytes("SCPI>",'ansi')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)

while True:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data == EXPECTED_RESPONSE:
        break
    time.sleep(0.1) # Wait a short period before trying again

s.close()

print("received data:", data)
```

In this code, we keep reading from the socket until we receive the 'SCPI>' prompt. Once we receive this prompt, we know that the LCR meter has finished processing our command and is ready to receive another command. After this point, you can send another command to the LCR meter and wait for the response in the same way.

Remember that this solution is a simple example and may not be suitable for all situations. If you're developing a more complex application, you might want to consider using a different approach, such as multithreading or asyncio, to handle communication with the LCR meter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this is another example, why this communication to device drives me crazy: your example **does not work** (in my case): 1. `TCP_PORT` has to be `5025`, 2. lineend `"\n"` is required and 3. the expected response **is not** `SCPI>`, instead, this will lead to an endless loop. The response after `*IDN?\n` is `Agilent ...`. Well, small differences, but these decide whether it's working or not. And if you go through all the well-meant, but uncomplete and non-working examples in the web, you are lost. I wish there was a webpage which explains all this in detail.

Comment: The answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT